# USB-2-PS2 adapter for mouse and keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I've got a KVM switch which takes input from keyboard and mouse on PS2 ports.
Recently I've changed my keyboard for the one with USB connection, got an USB-2-PS2 adapter,but couldn't find a purple one, so I bought the green one. I decided to give it a go and it did work fine for a while, until recently when I noticed that my computer acted as if I held the Ctrl key, where in fact I didn't. I plugged in my keyboard directly to the computer and that strange behavior disappeared, but it did happen only once.

My question:
Should this [item](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000Q6LTJO/ref=oss_product) work for me with USB keyboard connected to it?

UPDATE:
sorry, wrong link posted now, updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work. KVMs (even from reputable brands) occasionally drop events. When they drop a key press event, you tend not to notice it because you just assume you didn't press the key hard enough. From your description, your KVM dropped a key release event, which is noticeable. Pressing and releasing the affected key is usually enough to recover as it will send a new key release event.

Answer (score 0):

## YES!

your item is a **PS2 Female to USB-A Male Keyboard Adaptor** so it should work fine for either mouse or keyboard AFAIK, because mouse and keyboard are both on same PS2 standard.

And for that strange behavior it might be the Sticky key feature! and if you wonder what is sticky key **Press your “SHIFT” key 5 times in a row**.

Comment: Thank you for a swift answer. That's a good news, but I'm on Debian and the sticky key won't be the case here, I guess?

Comment: Will i am not quite Linux guy but i reckon it should be there on Debian Cause I remember it in Ubuntu.

Comment: just a note...in debian means probably in ubuntu, not necessarily the other way around.

Comment: @Aking, your right even thought its almost the same on the both ways, but still i said I reckon ;)